# Установка интерфейса Retrofit2 в зависимости от условия

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

Я хочу в зависимости от нажатой кнопки делать вывод разных данных, как мне правильно это реализовать? Я попытался в коде объявления ретрофита передать строку и в зависимости от её значения поставить нужный мне интерфейс, но выдает ошибку unresolved reference ввиду того что я изначально не даю переменной service её тип. Как мне грамотно это все реализовать?

```
internal fun getData(){
    var name: String? = intent.extras?.getString("name")

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BaseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

        val service = when (name) {
            this.getString(R.string.Button0) ->
                retrofit.create(GetAllLot::class.java)
            this.getString(R.string.Button1) ->
                retrofit.create(GetOneLot::class.java)
            else -> {}
        }
        val call = service.Beru()
}
```

```
interface GetLot {
    @GET("lots/?method=receive&type=all")
    fun BeruAll(): Call<List<GetLots>>
    @GET("lots/?method=receive&type=one")
    fun BeruOne(): Call<List<GetLots>>
}
```

Comment: Можно в `else` возвращать `null` и вызывать `val call = service?.Beru()`, но зачем вам два интерфейса?  Поместите в один интерфейс оба метода и вызывайте нужный в зависимости от условия.

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon Я добавил интерфейс, вы имели ввиду вот так?

Comment: Да, именно это я имел в виду. И лучше не называть так интерфейсы и классы, потому что Get подразумевает получить, а интерфейсы и классы ничего не дают, это структуры данных, их нужно называть существительными, а get использовать для методов как с `fun getData()`. Например для `interface LotService` для ретрофита, `class Lot` для данных, которые получаем.

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon Я пока учусь, в интерфейсах пишу для чего они Post, Get etc мне так проще ориентироваться просто в своих джунглях псевдокода (:
И благодарю!

Comment: Один интерфейс, один метод с параметром '@Query': https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Query.html

Answer (score 0):

```
object ServiceGenerator {

    private val BASE_URL = ""

    private val builder = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())

    private val retrofit = builder.build()

    private val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()

    fun <S> createService(serviceClass: Class<S>): S {
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass)
    }
}
```

А использовать так

```
 val serviceType = when (name) {
        this.getString(R.string.Button0) ->
            GetAllLot::class.java
        this.getString(R.string.Button1) ->
            GetOneLot::class.java
        else -> return
   }

   val service = ServiceGenerator.createService(serviceType)
   service.call()
```